# Reshuffling power series (aka Melvin–Morton expansion in knot theory)

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, knot-theory, power-series, quantum-topology

I am struggling to understand a statement which follows from some change of variables in a power series. I think that the context does not really matter here, so I will put it at the end of the question. Say that $V_\alpha (q)$ is a Laurent polynomial  in $q$ with integer coefficients (depending on some fixed integer $\alpha$) that can be written as a power series in $h=q-1$ as $$V_\alpha (q)= \sum_{n \geq 0} \left( \sum_{0 \leq m \leq n} D_{m,n} \alpha^{2m}  \right)h^n \quad, \quad D_{m,n} \in \mathbb{Q}.\tag{1}\label{1}$$ The coefficients $D_{m,n} $ satisfy the following property: there is a polynomial $\nabla (z) \in \mathbb{Z}[z^2]$ (with $\nabla (0)=1$) such that $$\sum_{m \geq 0} D_{m,2m} a^{2m} = \frac{1}{\nabla (e^{i \pi a}- e^{-i \pi a})} \tag{2}\label{2}$$ where $a$ is a formal parameter (see Question 1 below).

Rearrange \eqref{1} as a power series in $h$ and $\alpha h$ $$V_\alpha (q) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \left( \sum_{m \geq 0} D_{m,n+2m} (\alpha h)^{2m}  \right)h^n\tag{3}\label{3}$$ and replace the variable $\alpha h$ by $z := q^{\alpha /2 } - q^{-\alpha/2}$, so that
$$ \alpha h = 2 \log \left( \sqrt{ 1 + \frac{z^2}{4}    } + \frac{z}{2}  \right) \frac{h}{\log (1+h)}  = z + \mathcal{O}(z^3,h).\tag{4}\label{4}$$

Substituting \eqref{4} in \eqref{3} we  get a formal power series of $V_\alpha (q)$ in powers of $h$ and $z^2$: $$V_\alpha (q) = \sum_{n \geq 0} V^{(n)}(z) h^n.\tag{5}\label{5}$$

**Question 1:** How can equation \eqref{2} hold if the coefficients $D_{m,2m}$ are rational? For $\nabla (z)= 1+z^2$, the right-hand side of \eqref{2} expands as $$1+4 \pi ^2 a^2+\frac{44 \pi ^4 a^4}{3}+\frac{2408 \pi ^6 a^6}{45}+O\left(a^7\right)$$ (I expanded at $a=0$).

**Question 2:** By doing the change of variables, Eq. \eqref{2} should  imply that $$V^{(0)}(z)= \frac{1}{\nabla (z)}. $$  However I cannot see this. Since $V^{(0)}$ is the piece of $V_\alpha (q)$ independent of $h$ and $\alpha h = z + \mathcal{O}(z^3,h) $, we should have that $$V^{(0)} (z)=\sum_{m \geq 0} D_{m,n+2m} z^{2m},$$ but I cannot obtain from here $1/\nabla (z)$ .What should  $a$  in \eqref{2} be? Is \eqref{1} correct to start with?.

**Question 3:** Eq. \eqref{1} is supposed to be equivalent to a more common statement stating that if $q= e^{\hbar}$ and we write $$V_\alpha (q) = \sum_{ij} a_{ij} \alpha^i \hbar^j $$ then  $$ \sum_i a_{ii} \hbar^i = \frac{1}{\nabla (e^{\hbar /2}- e^{-\hbar /2})} \tag{6}\label{6}$$ How can one show that both statements are equivalent?

---

*Context.* This is part of the introduction of the paper

> Rozansky, L. [The universal $R$-matrix, Burau representation, and the Melvin–Morton expansion of the colored Jones polynomial](https://doi.org/10.1006/aima.1997.1661). Adv. Math. 134 (1998), no. 1, 1–31. MR1612375

The polynomial $V_\alpha (q)$ is the coloured Jones polynomial of a knot and $\nabla (z)$ is its Conway polynomial. Eq. \eqref{2} is the so-called Melvin–Morton expansion of  $V_\alpha (q)$. Eq. \eqref{6} is the statement of the Melvin-Morton expansion as proved by Bar-Natan and Garoufalidis in

> Bar-Natan, Dror; Garoufalidis, Stavros. [On the Melvin-Morton-Rozansky conjecture.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002220050070) Invent. Math. 125 (1996), no. 1, 103--133. MR1389962

Comment: MathJax note: instead of $$\text{formula}\qquad(\text{tag})$$ `\text{formula}\qquad(\text{tag})`, you can use $$\text{formula}\tag{tag}\label{unwanted-label}$$ `\text{formula}\tag{tag}\label{unwanted-label}` and then \eqref{unwanted-label} `\eqref{unwanted-label}`—and get a link for free.  (The only drawback is that labels are global *per page*, not per post, which is why I used a hopefully unwanted label `unwanted-label`.)  I have edited accordingly.